# Open Google Drive doc inside iOS app

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm trying to find a way to open a Google Drive document inside my iOS app, without integration the Drive UI stuff or opening Safari, but I cannot find anything on the guide.

Did someone ever do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use **UIDocumentInteractionController**, but it's only for local files, so first you need to download this document.

Comment: You can try using the [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios) on Drive REST API. It is a simple iOS application that makes requests to the Drive API. There is [sample app](https://github.com/googledrive/ios-quickeditor) that illustrate how to open and save files with the Google Drive API. If you will follow [Google Drive SDK: Writing your first Drive app on iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owlifMbV47k) tutorial to see that you don't have to fully integrate the Drive UI  to use its features in your app.